# mysql search where 3 columns for row have the same value

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id  -  in_id  -  nat_id
1      1         1     
2      1         3     
3      3         3     
4      2         1
```

Is it possible to select with mysql only the values in the above table which are the same across the 3 columns, ie return  1  and 3?

Or is this kind of filter only possible post query with php?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple query should work for you:

```
SELECT id
  FROM your_table
WHERE id = in_id
  AND nat_id = in_id
;
```

Check example at SQLFiddle: <kbd>[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69523/1)</kbd>